# Java Bluetooth Com Windows NRJavaSerial/RXTX

Tags: java, bluetooth, arduino

I am using Java with RXTX library and I have a problem. I want to read data from a Serial Port that is the bluetooth. If I use a normal COM port (usb arduino for example)and JAVA with RXTX, it works. If I use PUTTY, i can read the data from the bluetooth port.

If I use Java + RXTX and the bluetooth port, it doesn't work. If I use putty, and after that I want to display all ports, it works but only for one time, after that I cannot find the port anymore, like it break it. (not even in putty it doesn't work).

If I do not start PUTTY beforehand, It cannot even see the port. After the port is "broken" I have to turn off/on multiple times my bluetooth device. What seem to be the problem?

I did try the things listed here and it did not work : \
http://neophob.com/2011/05/serial-library-rxtx-v2-2pre5/
https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/1374.html

Any other thoughts?

Something is strange. Do you know what do I need to do so that the right rxtxSerial.dll is used? I have deleted every instance of rxtxSerial.dll from my PC and it still works???

Comment: I'm guessing you have a bluetooth device setup in Serial Port Profile (SPP) mode. My hunch is you should be able to open a single serial connection at a time (same as a typical wired serial connection) (e.g. from Java only, but not from Putty or any other serial terminal, or from Putty but not from Java or another serial: one connection at a time). What bluetooth module are you using ?

Comment: Yes, I am opening them one at a time. The module is integrated in my laptop BCM43142. Currently my solution is : Install a program to make and link two virtual ports and then using python bridge, one virtual and the bluetooth port. On java I listen to the other virtual port. This is really bad and clusterfuck but the only solution I found so far.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find what RxTxSerial.dll to replace. I deleted every instance from my pc and rebooted and the java application still works, so it doesn t even use it?

Comment: The python bridging does indeed sound a bit overkill. Are you locked to using the RXTX library or you can use any other library ? I haven't used Bluetooth in Java much, perhaps [BlueCove](http://www.bluecove.org/) might have the functionality you're after ?